# Modifying the params hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I'm creating a nested model in Rails, but I want to add fields to the nested models in the controller. I'm not using hidden_field_tag since it could be tampered with.

Here is my params hash:

```
 Parameters: {"dummy"=>{"users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"jjjj@gmail.com", "id"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"email"=>"qqq@gmail.com", "id"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Dummy"}
```

What I want is for there to be a field under each user_attributes called companyid. Let's say I wanted companyid  to be "company", then I thought that this would work:

```
len = params["dummy"]["users_attributes"].size
 counter = 0
 while counter < len
  params["dummy"]["users_attributes"][counter]["companyid" => "company"]
  counter = counter + 1
end
```

But, I get "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error for the first line in the while loop. I'm not exactly sure why.

Can someone help me out so I can modify the params hash?

EDIT:
So, I finally figured it out. I didn't really use any of the solutions exactly. First, I set a hidden_field tag to be blank for companyid.  Then, in my controller I put:

```
 params["dummy"]["users_attributes"].each do |key, val|
  params["dummy"]["users_attributes"][key]["companyid"] = "company"
 end
```

Not the most elegant code, but it'll work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The params hash is special since (especially with forms) is it mapped one-for-one with the model(s) it is related to, and Rails expects there to be either a database column, or a method in the model having that name.

Hidden fields are the typical solution to the problem of getting at additional data, but if you don't want users to see those fields, you run into the problem that HTTP is stateless.  So in this case, the `session[:something]` is your friend.  Before displaying a form or page that may have hidden data, instead add the data to a session variable (encrypt it first), which you can then read (and decrypt) when the user submits the form. Or you can save it in a database table and put only the row id in the session so the data can be read back when the form is posted.

If the data *was* part of the model, but you just didn't want to display it, you could just display the parts the user could see in the view, but then look up the rest of it in the controller action when the user submitted the form or request.

If the data is not *sensitive* you can just make sure to declare the values that the user can change as `attr_accessible` in their respective models (prevents mass assignment) and put the others in hidden fields.

Comment: I'm giving you the check because your in depth discussion of hidden fields allowed me to figure out a solution. Thanks!

Comment: What I lack in correctness, I make up for in verbosity.  I should have been a Java programmer!  (Oh, wait, I was).  So, what _was_ the solution?

Comment: It's in the edit of the original post: f.hidden_field :companyid in the form and then the code snippet above

Answer (score 0):

This looks ugly and I don't understand what is going on, but your mistake is:

```
len = params["dummy"]["users_attributes"].size
counter = 0
while counter < len
  params["dummy"]["users_attributes"][counter] = { "companyid" => "company" }
  counter = counter + 1
end
```

I believe you should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` here and initialize new companies in controller, not this ugly code

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
>
> http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Answer (score 0):

That's not how hashes work. Try this:

```
params["dummy"]["users_attributes"][counter]["companyid"] = "company"
```

**EDIT** In addition to fl00r's answer, yes, you'd have to set ["companyid"] to be {} first.